# How to create an article of the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bdd, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am testing the controllers with RSpec, FactoryGirls.
It is my factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |user|
    user.sequence(:name) { Faker::Internet.user_name }
    user.email Faker::Internet.email
    user.password "password"
    user.password_confirmation "password"
  end

  factory :article do
    user
    title Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
    content Faker::Lorem.paragraph(20)
  end
end
```

How can i create an article of the user here 
And this is articles_controller_spec

```
 describe ArticlesController do
      let(:user) do
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        user.confirm!
        user
      end

      describe "GET #index" do
        it "populates an array of articles of the user" do
          #how can i create an article of the user here
          sign_in user
          get :index
          assigns(:articles).should eq([article])
        end

        it "renders the :index view" do
          get :index
          response.should render_template :index
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: you want to test `create` action of `ArticlesController` ?

Comment: no, index action of ArticlesController

Comment: first i need to create an article and then check, where have u created articles of the user?

Comment: your `index` action is creating article ?

Comment: no, but i need to create one article just for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older version, instead of traits, is this:

```
describe ArticlesController do

  ..

  describe "GET #index" do
    it "populates an array of articles of the user" do

      article = FactoryGirl.create(:article, :user => user)

      sign_in user
      get :index
      assigns(:articles).should eq([article])
    end

  ..

end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can specify an User factory with articles already

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |user|
    user.sequence(:name) { Faker::Internet.user_name }
    user.email Faker::Internet.email
    user.password "password"
    user.password_confirmation "password"
  end

  factory :article do
    user
    title Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
    content Faker::Lorem.paragraph(20)
  end

  trait :with_articles do
    after :create do |user|
      FactoryGirl.create_list :article, 2, :user => user
    end
  end
end
```

then in your controller test

```
FactoryGirl.create :user, :with_articles # => returns user with 2 articles
```

**UPDATE**

i think you want to see all articles per user.. if thats the case use

`get :index, {:id => user.id}`

that way you look for the user and get all articles in your controller

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]);
@articles = @user.articles
```

if thats not the case then just doing

```
@articles =  Article.all
```

after using the `trait :with_articles` should display at least 2 `Articles`

you can test this with a simply asserting like
expect(@article.size).to eq(2)

Comment: how to get that created articles in controller_spec? I mean assign to a variable

Comment: in the let block.. instead of using `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` you use `FactoryGirl.create :user, :with_articles`.. and you have to pass the user id as params.. `get :index, {:id => user.id} (thats probably what you want)

Answer (score 1):

```
 describe ArticlesController do
    let(:user) do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      user.confirm!
      user
  end

   describe "GET #index" do
    it "populates an array of articles of the user" do
      #how can i create an article of the user here
      sign_in user
      get :index
      assigns(:articles).should eq([article])
    end

    it "renders the :index view" do
      get :index
      response.should render_template :index
    end

     it "assign all atricles to @atricles" do
       get :index
       assigns(:atricles).your_awesome_test_check #  assigns(:articles) would give you access to instance variable
     end
  end
end
```